# Crear una nueva columna con el valor numerico de otra en python

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo una columna tipo objet y quiero crear una nueva de tipo entero.

Código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.DataFrame()

nombres = ['Juan', 'Laura', 'Pepe','Maria']
edades = ["42 años", "40 años" , "37 años", "80 años"]

df['Nombre'] = nombres
df['Edad'] = edades

new_df = df.assign(edad_num=Edad)

  Nombre     Edad edad_num
0   Juan  42 años  42 años
1  Laura  40 años  40 años
2   Pepe  37 años  37 años
3  Maria  80 años  80 años
```

si intento cambiarla a tipo int me da error porque  "42 años" no es tipo int.
Como podria hacerlo?

Busco obtener esto:

```
  Nombre     Edad edad_num
0   Juan  42 años  42
1  Laura  40 años  40
2   Pepe  37 años  37
3  Maria  80 años  80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes extraer el número con [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['edad_num'] = df.Edad.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Explicación:

El método `extract()` recibe un `regex` (Del inglés Regular Expression) y puedes "filtrar" o "eliminar" los caracteres que no son números

Comment: Un simple `split` también funciona

Comment: Si el formato cambia sería difícil de adaptar un `split`, por ejemplo si el valor es `80años` o `años80`, por eso pensé en `extract` para obtener el valor numérico sin importar el orden de los datos

Comment: lo entiendo, esta perfecto :D

Comment: mil gracias como siempre!